# How do I replace each selected image src with another image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**CODE:**

```js
function selectIcon(event) {

    $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('selected');

    changeColor();
}

function changeColor() {

    var selectedIcon = $('.wrapper .feature.selected');

    var newIcon = selectedIcon.closest('.feature')
        .find('.feature-image img');
    newIcon.attr('src', newIcon.attr('src').replace('-old', ''));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="feature" onclick="selectIcon(event)">
        <div class="feature-image">
            <img src="img/A-old.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature" onclick="selectIcon(event)">
        <div class="feature-image">
            <img src="img/B-old.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature selected" onclick="selectIcon(event)">
        <div class="feature-image">
            <img src="img/C-old.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the selected image to another when I click it.

When I click A-old.png, it will be replaced by A.png. Then I click B-old.png, it will be replaced by B.png. (A&B are both selected)

But somehow all images I clicked are replaced by the same image.

I click A-old.png, it is replaced by A.png. Then I click B-old.png, it is also replaced by A.png.

update:

1. When the class is unselected, even though images are replaced by the new images, the color of the unselected image is dimmer than the currently selected image.
   [image]
2. I want to be able to unselect the icon when I click the icon again, the image will be replaced from new.png to old.png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cam simply use do everything in `one` function. Just the `onclick` function to determine which `img` div you have clicked on.

In the onclick function `selectIcon` - `this` refers the img we have clicked on.

The reason it was not working with your code is that you are telling the function which `img` to replace src of with. So the function was `replacing` everything where `150` was present

**Edit:** As you have added more information on the expected output you wanted. I have recreated the exact example of what you want. Run snippet below to see it working. I have a `blur` background as well to show which image is selected and replaced `onclick`.

I have added dummy image `src` when you click on it it will replaced by a `new` bigger image and if you click the same `bigger` image again it will revert back to `old` image. Same will happen for other images as well.

```js
function selectIcon(_this) {
  //get clicked img
  var div = $(_this).closest('.feature')

  //find clicked element img
  var newIcon = div.find('.feature-image img');

  //Add selected
  if (!div.hasClass('selected')) {
    div.addClass('selected')
    div.css({
      'background': 'rgb(0 0 0 / 8%)'
    })
    newIcon.attr('src', newIcon.attr('src').replace('150', '170'));
  } else {
    div.removeClass('selected')
    div.css({
      'background': 'none'
    })
    //Replace -old src with -new of the clicked item
    newIcon.attr('src', newIcon.attr('src').replace('170', '150'));

  }

  //Show new src
  var newSrc = newIcon.attr('src')
  //console.log(newSrc)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="feature" onclick="selectIcon(this)">
    <div class="feature-image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="feature" onclick="selectIcon(this)">
    <div class="feature-image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="feature" onclick="selectIcon(this)">
    <div class="feature-image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thx. I applied ur code, it works but not in the way I expect. Icons are replaced by new image, but when I select the 2nd icon,  since the 1st  is no longer "selected", the color of it is dimmer than the 2nd. I also want to be able to uncheck(unselect) the image so that the new png will back to old png. Still thank you but do u have any idea to fix them?

Comment: @Shangshang Sure. Your question was unclear before on the expected output you wanted. You have added more information now. I have edited my answer to meet you expectation as per the output mentioned in the question. Let me know.

Comment: thank you sooooooo much! It is exactly what I expected!!!!

Comment: @Shangshang Glad to hear that. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

you are toggling code on selected div. what about the other one which got selected. I have updated code where I am first trying to remove all the selected classes before specific div got selected.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="feature" onclick="selectIcon(event)">
   <div class="feature-image">
    <img width="20"  src="https://i0.wp.com/theturf.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/placeholder-old.png" />
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="feature" onclick="selectIcon(event)">
   <div class="feature-image">
    <img width="40" src="https://designshack.net/wp-content/uploads/placeholder-image-old.png" />
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="feature" onclick="selectIcon(event)">
   <div class="feature-image">
    <img width="40" src="https://complianz.io/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/placeholder-300x202-old.jpg" />
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here I removed selected class from all the divs.

```
function selectIcon(event) {
 $('body').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
 $(event.currentTarget).addClass('selected');
 changeColor(event.currentTarget);
}

function changeColor (event) {
var selectedIcon = $('.wrapper .feature.selected');
var newIcon = selectedIcon.find('.feature-image img');
newIcon.attr('src', newIcon.attr('src').replace('-old', ''));
}
```

for CSS in the first function I am removing all the selected classes which will be attached to div previously. so when at present one div gets clicked that specific div will be having the class **selected**.

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thx9urbj/1/

Comment: Hi, thank you for ur code. the old icons are replaced by new. However, it unselects the previous icon, so the color of the prev icon is dimmer than the current selected. I also want to be able to unselect the icon that when I click the icon again, the new image will go back to old. Do u have any thoughts to fix that? thank you